# Do I have to use the OpenGL data types (GLint, CLchar, ...) for a cross platform game?

Tags: c++, opengl, types, cross-platform

I have a short question. Why does OpenGL come with its own datatypes for standard types like int, unsigned int, char, and so on? And do I have to use them instead of the build in C++ datatypes?

For example the OpenGL equivalent to `unsigned int` is `GLuint` and for a c string there is `GLchar*` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> For example the OpenGL equivalent to `unsigned int` is `GLuint`

No it isn't, and that's exactly *why* you should use OpenGL's data types when interfacing with OpenGL.

`GLuint` is not "equivalent" to `unsigned int`. `GLuint` is *required* to be 32 bits in size. It is *always* 32-bits in size. `unsigned int` *might* be 32-bits in size. It might be 64-bits. You don't know, and C isn't going to tell you (outside of `sizeof`).

These datatypes will be defined for each platform, and they may be defined *differently* for different platforms. You use them because, even if they are defined differently, they will always come out to the same sizes. The sizes that OpenGL APIs expect and require.

Comment: So should I use the OpenGL types *only*?

Comment: @sharethis: Where? When? In what code? When you're doing what? You need them when you're *talking to OpenGL*. You use them when you're passing data for OpenGL to interpret. Whether you use them elsewhere is up to you.

Comment: So there won't be cross platform issues if I use simple `int` in my own classes of the game?

Comment: @sharethis: It depends. Do you use `int` in a non-cross-platform way? It sounds to me like you're really overthinking this whole thing.

Comment: I don't know what a non-cross-platform way would be, so I suggest not.

Comment: Are there any plans to migrate to `uint32_t`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: Well, since `uint32_t` and its ilk are not required by either the C or C++ standards, I'm guessing no.

Comment: OpenGL types are more reliable than stdint stypes? time to rewrite my data type definitions based on OpenGL header. Seriously, HOW IS STDINT LESS RELIABLE THAN OPENGL TYPES?!

Comment: @Dmitry: Because if you have access to an OpenGL implementation, then the OpenGL specification *requires* that you have access to the GL types. The OpenGL specification does not require that you have the "stdint" types. For example, in every version of Visual Studio before the one that included `<cstdint>`, you couldn't access the "stdint" types. But you *could* access the OpenGL ones.

Comment: @NicolBolas to be fair, Windows, does have its own required data type specifications which makes it trivial to create your own stdint.h via typedefs to windows types(BYTE, WORD, DWORD, INT32, ...). Doesn't take more than 10 minutes if you ignore the "fast" types.

Comment: @Dmitry: You wouldn't be relying on the actual C++ standard. You would be relying on the Windows platform. So I fail to see how it matters, one way or the other. Whether you're relying on the OpenGL implementation (ie: the header) or the platform you're using, what you *not relying on* is the Standard for Programming Language C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas if you are writing on the windows platform, you are relying on the windows platform, and since the windows itself relies on the windows platform, there's no reason not to bootstrap off it to obtain standard features that clean up program code. Since stdint.h is standard, as soon as you are moving away from windows, you already wrapped the windows types away in your own stdint.h, and your program remains portable... relatively. I am addressing your specific case when stdint.h isn't there. It's crucial for C programs to have a universal convention for fixed-size primitives.

Comment: @Dmitry: "*It's crucial for C programs to have a universal convention for fixed-size primitives.*" If it was so crucial for those types to exist... why are they *optional*? No C or C++ implementation is *required* to provide them in `stdint.h`/`cstdint`.

Comment: @Dmitry: I answered your question of "how is stdint less reliable than OpenGL types"? Because they existed before `stdint.h` came into being. And because the explicitly sized types they're required by the OpenGL specification, while they are optional for C and C++ implementations. Being optional is by definition less reliable than being mandatory.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's a fair point. They were there before stdint, and are required to be that size. My reluctance is largely due to any part of code using these opengl types cannot be reused outside opengl projects without changing all the types. On modern systems, stdint.h is far more accessible than gl.h, and stdint.h types are less stressful on the eyes  than opengl types.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not an expert of `OpenGL`, but usually frameworks/platforms such as `OpenGL`, `Qt`, etc. define their own datatypes so that the meaning and the capacity of the underlying datatype remains the same across different OSes. Usually this behavior is obtained using C/C++ preprocessor macros, but for what concerns `GLuint`, it seems to be just a `typedef` in `gl.h`:

```
typedef unsigned int GLuint;
```

So the answer is yes. You should use the framework's datatypes to ensure a good portability of your code within that framework across OSes.