# Ensuring OpenGL compatible types in c++

Tags: c++, opengl

OpenGL buffer objects support various data types of well defined width (`GL_FLOAT` is 32 bit, `GL_HALF_FLOAT` is 16 bit, `GL_INT` is 32 bit ...)

How would one go about ensuring cross platform and futureproof types for OpenGL?
For example, feeding `float` data from a c++ array to to a buffer object and saying its type is `GL_FLOAT` will not work on platforms where `float` isn't 32 bit.

Comment: Something wrong with `GLfloat` and friends?

Comment: @genpfault `GLfloat` guarantees no less than 32 bits, so it could be more on some platforms. That is true for all GL api typedefs.

Comment: @Aloalo: The GL typedefs will always match the GL data types on that particular platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285502/do-i-have-to-use-opengls-datatypes-glint-clchar-for-a-cross-platform-ga

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While doing some research on this, I noticed a subtle but interesting change in how these types are defined in the GL specs. The change happened between OpenGL 4.1 and 4.2.

Up to OpenGL 4.1, the table that lists the data types (Table 2.2 in the recent spec documents) has the header **Minimum Bit Width** for the size column, and the table caption says (emphasis added by me):

> GL types are not C types. Thus, for example, GL type int is referred to as GLint outside this document, and is not necessarily equivalent to the C type int. An implementation **may use more bits** than the number indicated in the table to represent a GL type. Correct interpretation of integer values outside the minimum range is not required, however.

Starting with the OpenGL 4.2 spec, the table header changes to **Bit Width**, and the table caption to:

> GL types are not C types. Thus, for example, GL type int is referred to as GLint outside this document, and is not necessarily equivalent to the C type int. An implementation **must use exactly the number of bits** indicated in the table to represent a GL type.

This influenced the answer to the question. If you go with the latest definition, you can use standard sized type definitions instead of the GL types in your code, and safely assume that they match. For example, you can use `int32_t` from `<cstdint>` instead of `GLint`.

Using the GL types is still the most straightforward solution. Depending on your code architecture and preferences, it might be undesirable, though. If you like to divide your software into components, and want to have OpenGL rendering isolated in a single component while providing a certain level of abstraction, you probably don't want to use GL types all over your code. Yet, once the data reaches the rendering code, it has to match the corresponding GL types.

As a typical example, say you have computational code that produces data you want to render. You may not want to have `GLfloat` types all over your computational code, because it can be used independent of OpenGL. Yet, once you're ready to display the result of the computation, and want to drop the data into a VBO for OpenGL rendering, the type has to be the same as `GLfloat`.

There are various approaches you can use. One is what I mentioned above, using sized types from standard C++ header files in your non-rendering code. Similarly, you can define your own typedefs that match the types used by OpenGL. Or, less desirable for performance reasons, you can convert the data where necessary, possibly based on comparing the `sizeof()` values between the incoming types and the GL types.